# MySQL: If values exist do an update on the row, if values do not exist do an insert

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I need an sql statement that will update if the row exists and insert if the row doesn't exist. 
I have a table with the following values...

id is (Unique + auto increment)

```
id | selectedID | userID  | question
------------------------------------
1  |    1       |   3     |   10
```

if the user with userID 3 selects a different selectedID e.g. 2 for question 10 i want the table to update to:

```
id | selectedID | userID  | question
-----------------------------------
1  |    2       |   3     |   10
```

And if the user with userID 3 selects selectedID 2 again for question 10 i don't want this to insert another row.

If the user with id 3 selects a selectedID for question 11 I want it to insert a new row e.g. 2 for question 11:

```
id | selectedID | userID  | question
-----------------------------------
1  |    2       |   3     |   10
2  |    2       |   3     |   11
```

Comment: What is your question? Where's your code? Where are you stuck? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `insert on duplicate key update`.

Basically, you want the combination `(userId, questionId)` to be unique.  First set up a unique constraint/index:

```
create unique index unq_t_userId_questionId on t(userId, questionId);
```

Then use `on duplicate key update` for your inserts:

```
insert into t (userId, questionId, selectedId)
    values (@userId, @questionId, @selectedId)
    on duplicate key update selectedId = values(selectedId);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks @GordonLinoff!

Answer (score 0):

[INSERT on duplicate key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

You can use above construct in mysql which will update the record if key is present, if primary key not found makes an insert. Somewhat MERGE does in oracle.

> If you specify the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option in the INSERT
>   statement and the new row causes a duplicate value in the UNIQUE or
>   PRIMARY KEY index, MySQL performs an update to the old row based on
>   the new values.